# Flutter Intl plugin used with dynamic Strings

Tags: flutter, flutter-intl

I am using the Flutter Intl plugin by Localizely to localize my App.
I generated arb files for the languages I want and begin to introduces the translations.

For example:

```
{
  "documentsSection": "All the documents",
  "favouritesSection": "Favourites",
  "newsSection": "News",
  "settingsSection": "Settings"
}
```

Everytime I want to localize a text I use:

```
S.of(context).favouritesSection;
```

And it works perfectly.

However, when I have a List like this:

```
List<Strings> sectionTitles = ["documentsSection","favouritesSection","newsSection","settingsSection"]
```

And I am inside an itemBuilder loop like this one:

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  String sectionName = sectionTitles[index];
                  return Text(
                      S.of(context).sectionName,
                  ),
                },
```

Obviously this doens't work, as "sectionName" is not a key in the arb file. But I think that the code express what I want to achieve.
May be someone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Another way to solve this is by using the **Select ICU format** kind of messages.
Note, this solution may introduce some constraints, but on the other hand, it is more elegant.

String key declaration:

```
"sectionTitles": "{section, select, documentsSection {Documents section} favouritesSection {Favourites section} newsSection {News section} settingsSection {Settings section} other {Section}}",
"@sectionTitles": {
  "placeholders": {
    "section": {}
  }
}
```

String key usage:

```dart
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  String sectionName = sectionTitles[index];
                  return Text(
                      S.of(context).sectionTitles(sectionName),
                  ),
                },
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for!

Comment: Great, I'm glad it helped!

Comment: It's hard to understand the first code snippet. It would be easier with some explanation

Comment: @Ced I know it's a bit late, but [here (link)](https://lokalise.com/blog/complete-guide-to-icu-message-format/#Switch_with_select) is the explanation of the **Select** format. Basically it goes like this: 
`{varName, select, optionOne {translation of 1st option} secondOption {2nd option's translation} other {whatever doesn't get matched before gives this text}}`

Comment: @ZoranLuledzija hvala Zorane!

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two ways to achieve what you want.

The first is creating a function that maps your `sectionTitles` to your intl strings, something like this:

```dart
  String getSectionTitle(BuildContext context, String title) {
    if (title == "documentsSection") {
      return S.of(context).documentsSection;
    } else if (title == "favouritesSection") {
      return S.of(context).favouritesSection;
    } else if (title == "newsSection") {
      return S.of(context).newsSection;
    } else if (title == "settingsSection") {
      return S.of(context).settingsSection;
    }
  }
```

And using like this:

```dart
...
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  return Text(
    getSectionTitle(context, sectionTitles[index]),
  );
},
...
```

---

The second is making an array with your intl strings:

```dart
List<String> sectionTitles = [
      S.of(context).documentsSection,
      S.of(context).favouritesSection,
      S.of(context).newsSection,
      S.of(context).settingsSection,
];
```

But you would need to create this inside your build function because you need a context:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> sectionTitles = [
      S.of(context).documentsSection,
      S.of(context).favouritesSection,
      S.of(context).newsSection,
      S.of(context).settingsSection,
    ];
    return ...
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Text(
              sectionTitles[index],
            );
          },
    ...
  }
```

Another way of achieving this without using the context from your build function is by using the `didChangeDependencies` method available on `StatefulWidgets`, like this:

```dart
 List<String> sectionTitles;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    sectionTitles ??= [
      S.of(context).documentsSection,
      S.of(context).favouritesSection,
      S.of(context).newsSection,
      S.of(context).settingsSection,
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ...       
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Text(
              sectionTitles[index],
            );
          },
    ...
  }
```

Note that in this case, you cannot use `initState` because it wouldn't provide a context with the intl strings already available, thus we use `didChangeDependencies`.

If you are wondering what does the `??=` does, it simply checks if a variable (in this case `sectionTitles`) is null, and if it is, it will assign the values to it. We use it here to avoid redefining the `sectionTitles` every time.